# Looking for ConTeXt examples

Tags: context

On the internet you find a lot of ready-to-typeset LaTeX examples (often called templates) on websites such as [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/) or [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates).  These allow novices to produce documents really quickly and more advanced users can find out how to achieve a certain layout.

Being developed by a company, ConTeXt has a lot more momentum than LaTeX and offers interesting features that currently cannot be realised in LaTeX.  Another compelling thing is the mostly consistent syntax, essentially being `\setup...`, `\start...`, `\stop...`.  More reasons are listed in the thread [Why should I be interested in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4987).

ConTeXt is also extensively documented, see [Where can I find good ConTeXt documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2839), but I'm missing concrete examples for things like

- How to write a CV in ConTeXt?
- How to make a conference poster in ConTeXt?
- How to design presentation slides in ConTeXt?

Basically, examples for all the categories listed on [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/).

Comment: There aren't that many templates. The idea behind ConTeXt is that it's fairly easy to create your own template based on your particular needs. There are templates for letters, slide presentations, etc. and also the source of most of the manuals is available. You may mention what you want to achieve or at least tell us what type of template you need.

Comment: plus the OP quoted Website is not correct, see my first post.

Comment: @SteveHodgkinson You are right the wiki is nice. I edited my comment on it, was a bit harsh.

Comment: @SteveHodgkinson your URL is wrong, there is a `]` at the end giving an error when you visit the page.

Comment: People are often after 'templates' but beyond `\starttext ... \stoptext` it's difficult to know what to say here.

Comment: @SteveHodgkinson this was actually the only example I found so far. Better than nothing, but I was looking at a more thematic approach regarding the kind of document you can produce using ConTeXT, and start from one of those. Anyway, will try to do it from scratch.

Comment: @Marco Thanks for your time. I did not find any of those templates. I am looking to produce a document structured like a scientific article, including figures, references, columns ect...

Comment: Personally I've been looking forwards to use ConTeXt but it's true that it's lacking templates and proper documentation (they are working on this). I hope it gets better. I personally learn much more by example, seeing tons of documents, and then looking at the source to see how a particular thing was done; and I haven't been able to do it in ConTeXt yet.

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for in a template. You can look at the modules for some journals: [MAPS](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modules/Maps) ([source](https://bitbucket.org/phg/context-mirror/src/b162038956eefaaa786603e8faceff35016bdc82/tex/context/modules/mkiv/s-map-10.mkiv?at=beta&fileviewer=file-view-default)), [PracTeX](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modules/Pracjourn) ([source](https://bitbucket.org/phg/context-mirror/src/b162038956eefaaa786603e8faceff35016bdc82/tex/context/modules/mkii/s-ptj-01.mkii?at=beta&fileviewer=file-view-default))

Comment: @Aditya Thanks, you could make an answer of it.

Comment: Actually, I am looking for ConTeXt *examples* (which is what you are also after, probably).  Would you allow me to rephrase your question and put a bounty on it?

Comment: @HenriMenke yes please do :)

Comment: there are a couple of CV-templates on http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Curriculum_Vitae

Comment: @HenriMenke: I also use ConTeXt to generate homework assignments and slides. An old version of the homework macros are available on [PracTeX](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/mahajan/). The slides macros build up on the basic idea [that I blogged about](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/creating-a-clean-presentation-style-in-40-commits/). For examples, see [my academic webpage](http://www.ece.mcgill.ca/~amahaj1/talks.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a real-world example. I am an academic and I write my grant proposals using ConTeXt. The formatting guidelines are relatively simple (use this font, set these margins, and that's about it). I usually submit to two funding agencies, FRQNT and NSERC, and they have slightly different formatting instructions. Occasionally, I also write a generic proposal that is submitted to other agencies.

I have a private module `p-proposal` to take care of the different formatting requirements. Since this was for personal use, most of it was undocumented. I have added brief explanations in the comments; if something doesn't make sense, feel free to ask:

```
\startmodule proposal

\setupmodule[size=10pt, alternative=default]

\processaction
  [\currentmoduleparameter{alternative}]
  [
    default=>{\enablemode[compact]},
    frqnt=>{\enablemode[frqnt]},
    nserc=>{\enablemode[nserc]},
  ]

% Grants to FRQNT should be in 10bp. 
\startmode[frqnt]
  \setupmodule[site=10bp]
\stopmode

% Grants to NSERC should be in 12pt.
\startmode[nserc]
  \setupmodule[size=12pt]
\stopmode

% Enable microtype protrusion. 
\definefontfeature
  [default]
  [default]
  [protrusion=quality,expansion=quality]

\setupalign[hanging,tolerant]

% Most grant agencies want Times. Use MS Times rather than
% some other clone like Termes; I once had a grant application
% returned because pdffonts didn't list Times!
\usetypescriptfile[mscore]
\usetypescriptfile[texgyre]
\usetypescriptfile[euler]

\starttypescript[mainface]
  \definetypeface [mainface][rm][serif][mscoretimes][default]
  \definetypeface [mainface][ss][sans] [helvetica][default] [rscale=auto]
  \definetypeface [mainface][tt][mono] [modern]   [default] [rscale=auto]
  \definetypeface [mainface][mm][math] [pagellaovereuler]  [default]
                  [rscale=0.9]
\stoptypescript

% I tend to use math sparingly, therefore the math font is Euler. 
% Set all math characters to be upright rather than italic.
\setupmathematics[default=normal, lcgreek=normal, ucgreek=normal]

% I don't like Euler bullets (when used in itemize); take bullets
% from the text font instead.
\setupsymbolset[text]

% MS Times does not have small caps. The headers are typeset in small caps.
% So, use Termes for headers.
\starttypescript[headerface]
  \definetypeface [headerface][rm][serif][termes][default]
  \definetypeface [headerface][ss][sans] [helvetica][default] [rscale=auto]
  \definetypeface [headerface][tt][mono] [modern]   [default] [rscale=auto]
  \definetypeface [headerface][mm][math] [pagellaovereuler]  [default] [rscale=auto]
\stoptypescript

\setupbodyfont[headerface] % To initialize the header font globally
\setupbodyfont[mainface,\currentmoduleparameter{size}]

% \em should be italic rather than slanted.
\definebodyfontenvironment[default][em=italic]  

% Many funding agencies cannot handle a higher PDF version, sigh!
\pdfminorversion 4

\setuppapersize[letter][letter]

\setuplayout[
                   width=middle,
                  height=middle,
                location=middle,
                topspace=0.75in,
             bottomspace=0.75in,
                  bottom=0.25in,
               backspace=1in,
                cutspace=1in,
              leftmargin=.45in,
             rightmargin=.45in,
      leftmargindistance=0.05in,
     rightmargindistance=0.05in,
                  header=0.20in,
                  footer=0.20in,
           headerdistance=0.05in,
          footerdistance=0.05in,
        ]

\startmode[compact,frqnt, nserc]
  \setuplayout
    [
      topspace=0.5in, bottomspace=0.5in, 
      backspace=0.75in, cutspace=0.75in, width=middle,
      footer=0pt, footerdistance=0pt,
    ]
\stopmode

\startmode[frqnt,nserc]
  \setupinterlinespace[line=12.25bp]
\stopmode

\setuppagenumbering[location=]
\setupheader[style={\switchtobodyfont[headerface]\sc}]
\setupfooter[style={\switchtobodyfont[headerface]\sc}]
\setupbottom[style={\switchtobodyfont[headerface]\sc}]

\setupbackgrounds[header][text][bottomframe=on]

\startmode[compact]
  \setuphead[section,subject]
            [number=no, style=bold, alternative=text,before={\blank[small]},distance=0.25em,after=]
  \def\deepstructuretitlecommand#1{#1:}
\stopmode

\setuphead[title][alternative=middle, style=\ssbfb]

\startnotmode[compact]
  \setuphead[section,subject]
            [style=\ssbfa, before={\blank[big]}, after={\blank[medium]}]
  \setuphead[subsection,subsubject]
            [style=\ssbf, before={\blank[medium]}, after={\blank[small]}]
\stopnotmode

\startmode[frqnt, nserc]
  \setuphead[section,subject]
            [style=\bfa,before={\blank[small]}, after={\blank[none]}]
  \setuphead[subsection,subsubsection]
            [style=\bf,%alternative=text,
             deeptextcommand=\groupedcommand{}{\removeunwantedspaces:}, 
             distance=1ex,
             before={\blank[small]}]

  \setuphead[subsection,subsubsection, subsubsubsection, subsubject]
            [style=\bf,alternative=text,
             deeptextcommand=\groupedcommand{}{\removeunwantedspaces:}, 
             distance=1ex,
             before={\blank[small]}]
\stopmode

% Be more linient with hyphenation.
\definebreakpoint [compound] [-] [nleft=2,nright=2]
\setbreakpoints   [compound]

\setupindenting[medium,yes]
\setupwhitespace[none]
\setupblank[halfline]

\startmode[compact]
  \setupitemize[nowhite]
  \setupitemize[margin=2em]
\stopmode

\definehighlight[important][style=bolditalic]
\definecolor[lightyellow][r=1,g=1,b=0.88]

\setupframedtext
  [
    width=broad,
    offset=5bp,
    align={hanging,hz},
    background={color},
    backgroundcolor=lightyellow,
    rulethickness=1bp,
    frame=on,
    framecolor=black,
  ]

\setupitemize[autointro, broad, fit]
\setupitemize[distance=0.5em, indentnext=auto]

\definetabulate[titletabulate][|k0lB|i1p|]
\setuptabulate[titletabulate][unit=0.25em]

\setupcaptions[style={\small\setupinterlinespace}, distance=0.5em]
\setupfloats[sidespaceafter=0pt]

\setupformula 
    [
      spacebefore={nowhite,fixed,quarterline}, 
      spaceafter={back,fixed,nowhite,halfline},
    ]

\stopmodule
```

To show the output, I use the following test file:

```
% Change the alternative for different results
\usemodule[proposal][alternative=default]

% The header should be the title of the grant and the PIN of the PI
\startmode[nserc,frqnt]
  \setupheadertexts[\fakewords{3}{4}][PIN: 12345]
\stopmode

\usemodule[visual]

\starttext
%In the generic proposal, the title is given at the top
\startnotmode[frqnt,nserc]
\starttitletabulate
  \NC Project \NC \fakewords{5}{10}  \NC \NR
  \NC Investigators \NC \fakewords{3}{5}  \NC \NR
\stoptitletabulate
\stopnotmode

\dorecurse{6}
  {\section{\fakewords{3}{7}}
   \dorecurse{2}
     {\fakewords{100}{200}\endgraf
     \placefigure[left]{\fakewords{4}{8}}{\fakeimage{4cm}{3cm}{5cm}{6cm}}
     \dorecurse{2}{\fakewords{100}{200}\endgraf}}}

\stoptext
```

With `alternative=frqnt` the output is

[image]

With `alternative=nserc` the output is almost the same but uses a bigger font:

[image]

With `alternative=default`, the output is:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is mine.
It's still a *work in progress* , i'm managing to put a header in arabic/french with a logo using `\framed`

---

```
 \setuppapersize[A4]
 \mainlanguage[fr]
 \usemodule[chart]
  %\setuplayout[backspace=3.5cm,width=14cm]
   \usesymbols[fontawesome]
   \setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided,location=]
   %\setupheader[text][after=\hrule]
   %\setupheadertexts[]
   %\setupheadertexts[\setups{text a}][][\setups{text b}][]
   %\startsetups[text a]
   %  \hskip-1.5cm
   %  \framed[frame=off,width=17cm,offset=none]{
    %  \rlap{Cardiologie} 
   %  \hfill
   %  {\darkred \ss Clinique EL ABRAR}
   %  \hfill
   %  \llap{\pagenumber}}
   %\stopsetups
   %\startsetups[text b]
   %  \hskip-1.5cm
   %  \framed[frame=off,width=17cm,offset=none]{
   %  \rlap{\tfxx \ss 15 Rue Tolozane Les Palmiers, Oran}
   %  \hfill
   %  {Clinique EL ABRAR}
   %  \hfill
   %  \llap{\pagenumber}}
   %\stopsetups
   \definecolor[abrar][r=0.02,g=0.49,b=0.52]
   \definefontfeature[default][default][onum=yes]
   %\definefallbackfamily [texgyre] [serif] [amiriregular] [range=arabic]
   %\define[1]\Arab{\setuplayout[r2l] \texgyre#1}
   \definefontfamily[texgyre][serif][merriweather]
   \definefontfamily[texgyre][sans] [merriweathersans]
   \definefontfamily[texgyre][mono] [TeX Gyre Cursor][features=none]
   \definefontfamily[texgyre][math] [TeX Gyre Pagella Math]
   \setupbodyfont[texgyre,11pt]
   \setupfootertexts[\tfx Rapport médical --- Page \currentpage\ de               \lastpage  ---  Le \currentdate]
   \setuphead[subject][color=abrar,style=\ssb \bf] 
   \setuphead[subsubject][color=abrar, style=\ss\tfb\bi]
   \edef\defaultlineheight{\the\lineheight}
   \startMPdefinitions
    newpath basicShape;
    basicShape := unitsquare ;

    DefaultLineHeight := \defaultlineheight;
   \stopMPdefinitions

   \startuseMPgraphic {unnumberedbullet}
    fill basicShape scaled OverlayWidth shifted (0, 0.5*LineHeight)
       withcolor \MPcolor{darkred};
   setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox;
   \stopuseMPgraphic

   \startuseMPgraphic {numberedbullet}
     fill basicShape xyscaled (0.9*DefaultLineHeight,         0.9*DefaultLineHeight)
    shifted (-0.5(0.9*DefaultLineHeight - OverlayWidth, 0))
       withcolor \MPcolor{abrar};
     setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox;
     \stopuseMPgraphic

     \defineoverlay[unnumberedbullet][\useMPgraphic{unnumberedbullet}] 
     \defineframed [unnumberedbullet]
          [
            frame=off,
            width=0.5\bodyfontsize,
            background=unnumberedbullet,
            location=low,
          ]

     \definesymbol[unnumberedbullet]
         [{\unnumberedbullet{}}]


     \defineoverlay[numberedbullet][\useMPgraphic{numberedbullet}]
     \defineframed [numberedbullet]
          [
            frame=off,
            width=\lineheight,
            background=numberedbullet,
            foregroundcolor=white,
             % Center the number against capital letters, ignoring  character descent
            location=depth,
            foregroundstyle={\small\small}, % better to define a custom fontswitch
          ]


      \definesymbol[numberedbullet]
         [{\numberedbullet{\currentitemnumber}}]
       \defineframedtext[cadrevert]
     [background=screen,backgroundscreen=.85,
      width=0.9\textwidth,
     frame=off,
     leftframe=on,
     framecolor=darkred,
     rulethickness=3pt]
     \usemodule[symb-imp-fontawesome]
     \usesymbols[fontawesome]
     \setupbodyfont[10pt]
                    %%%%%
     \starttext
     \startalignment[middle]
     \dontleavehmode
     \framed
     [background=color,backgroundcolor=darkred,
     backgroundoffset=5pt,corner=0,frame=0,
     foreground=color,foregroundcolor=white]
     {\ssc \bf RAPPORT MÉDICAL}
     \stopalignment
     \blank[3*big]

    \startitemize[unnumberedbullet,columns,two,stretch]
    \startitem { \bf \ss Nom \& prénoms\hspace[medium]} {\sc Hamid Bougherara} \stopitem
    \startitem {\bf \ss Date de naissance \hspace[medium]} 17/02/2000          \stopitem
    \startitem {\bf\ss Adresse \hspace[medium]} { Aïn Témouchent}   \stopitem
    \startitem {\bf\ss Médecin réferent\hspace[big]} {\sc Dr Hamid}     \stopitem
     %\raggedleft 
      \startitem {\bf\ss Motifs \hspace[big]} angine de poitrine\\
       dyspnée
       \stopitem
     \startitem {\ss\bf Date \hspace[big]} \currentdate \stopitem
     \stopitemize
     \subject{ANTÉCÉDENTS - FDR}
     \startitemize[unnumberedbullet]
     \startitem {\bf \ss Diabète:} bien équilibré sous traitement {\abrar  Glucophage 850mg} \stopitem
     \startitem {\bf \ss HTA:} bien équilibré sous traitement Triatec     \stopitem
     \stopitemize
     \startcadrevert
     Au total il s'agit de Mr {\sc Hamid Bougherara} aux antécedents de     {\bf angine de poitrine} dont le test d'ischémie est revenu positif pour     les territoires \abrar postérieurs.
   \stopcadrevert
    \subject{Dispositions complémentaires}


 \stoptext
```

---

as you can see i had experienced a few tips with this very draft. Hope it helps

### Edit

Here is a less *quick'n'dirty* example, with a header (bidi) and a footer using tabulate environment and fontAwesome symbols.

```
\setuppapersize[A4]
 \mainlanguage[fr]
%\usemodule[chart]
\setuplayout[header=3.5cm,headerdistance=1cm,margin=2.5cm,footer=2.5cm]
\usesymbols[fontawesome]
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided,location=]
\definecolor[abrar][r=0.02,g=0.49,b=0.52]
\definefontfeature[default][default][onum=yes]

\definefontfamily[merry][serif][merriweather]
\definefontfamily[merry][sans] [merriweathersans]
\definefontfamily[merry][mono] [TeX Gyre Cursor][features=none]
\definefontfamily[merry][math] [TeX Gyre Pagella Math]


\definelayer[mybg]  % name of the layer
 [x=0mm, y=0mm, % from upper left corner of paper
  width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight, % let the layer cover the full  paper
   ]

 \setupbackgrounds[page][background=mybg]
 \setupdirections[bidi=global]
 \definefontfeature
  [arabic]
  [mode=node,language=dflt,script=arab,
   init=yes,medi=yes,fina=yes,isol=yes,
   liga=yes,dlig=yes,rlig=yes,clig=yes,
   mark=yes,mkmk=yes,kern=yes,curs=yes,
    saed=yes]

 \starttypescript [serif] [arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Regular] [mothanna] [features=arabic]
  \stoptypescript

 \starttypescript [serif] [arabic] [name]
 \definefontsynonym [Serif]     [Arabic-Regular] [features=arabic]
 \stoptypescript

 \starttypescript [mothanna]
 \definetypeface [mothanna] [rm] [serif] [arabic] [default]
 \stoptypescript

 \usetypescriptfile[type-mothanna]
 \usetypescript[mothanna]
%\pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT \textdir TRT
 \setupbodyfont[merry,10pt]

 \setuphead[subject][color=abrar,style=\ssa\bf] 
 \setuphead[subsubject][color=abrar, style=\ss\tfb\bi]
 \edef\defaultlineheight{\the\lineheight}
 \startMPdefinitions
   newpath basicShape;
    basicShape := unitsquare ;

  DefaultLineHeight := \defaultlineheight;
 \stopMPdefinitions

 \startuseMPgraphic {unnumberedbullet}
 fill basicShape scaled OverlayWidth shifted (0, 0.5*LineHeight)
   withcolor \MPcolor{darkred};
  setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox;
 \stopuseMPgraphic

  \startuseMPgraphic {numberedbullet}
   fill basicShape xyscaled (0.9*DefaultLineHeight,   0.9*DefaultLineHeight)
   shifted (-0.5(0.9*DefaultLineHeight - OverlayWidth, 0))
       withcolor \MPcolor{abrar};
    setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox;
   \stopuseMPgraphic

  \defineoverlay[unnumberedbullet][\useMPgraphic{unnumberedbullet}]
  \defineframed [unnumberedbullet]
          [
            frame=off,
            width=0.5\bodyfontsize,
            background=unnumberedbullet,
            location=low,
          ]

  \definesymbol[unnumberedbullet]
         [{\unnumberedbullet{}}]


 \defineoverlay[numberedbullet][\useMPgraphic{numberedbullet}]
 \defineframed [numberedbullet]
          [
            frame=off,
            width=\lineheight,
            background=numberedbullet,
            foregroundcolor=white,
            % Center the number against capital letters, ignoring character descent
            location=depth,
            foregroundstyle={\small\small}, % better to define a custom fontswitch
          ]


 \definesymbol[numberedbullet]
         [{\numberedbullet{\currentitemnumber}}]
  \defineframedtext[cadrevert]
  [background=screen,backgroundscreen=.85,
   width=0.9\textwidth,
  frame=off,
  leftframe=on,
  framecolor=darkcyan,
  rulethickness=3pt]

  \setupheadertexts[\setups{tableheader}]

 \startsetups tableheader
 \starttabulate[|p|lrw(2cm)|pr|]
 \NC \ss Clinique médico chirurgicale El Abrar\NC          \externalfigure[logo.png][width=2cm, location=inline]\NC \setupalign[r2l]     \switchtobodyfont[mothanna]{ العيادة الطبية الجراحية الأبرار}\NC \NR
   \NC \setupalign[l2r]\ss Service de cardiologie\NC \NC  \setupalign[r2l] \switchtobodyfont[mothanna]{ مصلحة أمراض القلب}\NC\NR
  \setupalign[l2r]
   \NC \ss\tfx Dr Yahyaoui .M.K \NC  \NC \ss\tfx  kaddourkardio(at)gmail.com \NC \NR
  \stoptabulate      
  \stopsetups
  \setuppagenumbering[location={header,margin}]
 \setupfootertexts[\setups{tablefooter}]

  \startsetups tablefooter 
  \startframed[frame=off,
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=lightgray,
    style={\ss\tfx}]
    \starttabulate[|lw(.5cm)|p|rw(1cm)|p|]
   \NC \symbol[fontawesome][ambulance] \NC 15,rue Tolozane Les palmiers,  Oran \NC \symbol[fontawesome][phone] \NC (+213) 041-496-066 \NC\NR
   \NC \symbol[fontawesome][fax] \NC(+213) 041-233-491 
   \NC \symbol[fontawesome][mobile] \NC (+213) 0561 882-066\NC\NR
   \NC \symbol[fontawesome][envelope-o] \NC clinique-elabrar\symbol[fontawesome][at]laposte.net\NC \symbol[fontawesome][mobile]    \NC (+213) 0561 882-066\NC\NR
 \stoptabulate
 \stopframed
 \stopsetups

  \starttext
  \startalignment[middle]
  \blank[big]
   \dontleavehmode
  \framed
   [background=color,backgroundcolor=darkred,
    backgroundoffset=5pt,corner=0,frame=0,
    foreground=color,foregroundcolor=white]
    {\ssc \bf RAPPORT MÉDICAL}
   \stopalignment
    \blank[2*big]
    \startitemize[unnumberedbullet,columns,two,stretch]
   \startitem { \bf \ss Nom \& prénoms\hspace[medium]} {\sc Hamid Bougherara} \stopitem
   \startitem {\bf \ss Date de naissance \hspace[medium]} 17/02/2000     \stopitem
   \startitem {\bf\ss Adresse \hspace[medium]} { Aïn Témouchent}     \stopitem
   \startitem {\bf\ss Médecin réferent\hspace[big]} {\sc Dr Hamid}     \stopitem
    %\raggedleft 
   \startitem {\bf\ss Motifs \hspace[big]} angine de poitrine\\
   \stopitem
   \startitem {\ss\bf Date \hspace[big]} \currentdate \stopitem
   \stopitemize
   \subject{ANTÉCÉDENTS - FDR}
  \startitemize[unnumberedbullet]
   \startitem {\bf \ss Diabète:} bien équilibré sous traitement {\abrar    Glucophage 850mg} \stopitem
   \startitem {\bf \ss HTA:} bien équilibré sous traitement Triatec     \stopitem
  \stopitemize
  \subject{Dispositions complémentaires}

  Au total il s'agit de Mr {\sc Hamid Bougherara} aux antécedents de     {\bf angine de poitrine} dont le test d'ischémie est revenu positif pour les    territoires {\abrar postérieurs}.


  \stoptext
```