# Templates for ConTeXt

Tags: context, templates

I only found this here post ( [Looking for ConTeXt examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307842/looking-for-context-examples?r=SearchResults) ) which almost hit the spot.

**Main question: is there a website dedicated to ConTeXt templates?**

**Subquestion: if not existing, is someone intending its creation?**

**Further information possibly relevant:**
I saw examples, have the manual, and so on, see more or less how one might use it, and will probably not fully transition to ConTeXt for now. I find ConTeXt a very attractive option for TeX or alongside LaTeX, and having templates might help learning it better. In addition, if there are easily found templates, this may, as far as I know, help ConTeXt become more popular, which is a good aim.

Comment: As a regular ConTeXt user I am not aware of any dedicated page. The ConTeXtgarden has some examples but real templates are of rare use for most documents, I think. The most setup tasks in ConTeXt are only a few lines (especially page layout). And for special tasks (grids, tables, XML) there are the manuals with some examples, yet no templates. Bottom line: I have not seen a collection of templates yet.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a package, font, tool, book or other off-site resource** are off-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it or, if applicable, ask on [Software Recommendations SX](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I've gone through the webpages (help center, and related links) regarding the matter, and I haven't seen anything specific or clear warranting closure. Can someone, if he is sufficiently knowledgable and wise about the matter, point out which part specifically supports closing this thread?